# How to find types of all attributes of an object in Python?

Tags: python, types, attributes

I have a tensor

`x = torch.tensor([1, 2, 3])`

I did this

`len(dir(x))`

which gave this,

464

I want to know how many of these 464 attributes are builtin_function_or_method, or method, or any other type.

how do I list the type of the attributes of a tensor?

Comment: You mean  `[getattr(x, i) for i in dir(x)]`

Comment: I got it, by this [(f'x.{i}', type(getattr(x, i))) for i in dir(x)]

Comment: Let me add also `cc=[(f'x.{i}', type(getattr(x, i))) for i in dir(x)]` after which `for ii in range(len(cc)): print(cc[ii])`

Answer (score 2):

`help(x)` generates some basic documentation on whatever you pass in. It'll tell you the type of the object, attributes, methods on it, etc.

Answer (score 0):

this is what I did to get types of all attributes of a tensor

import modules, create tensor

```
import torch
from collections import defaultdict

x = torch.tensor([1., 2., 3.])
```

below list comprehension gives a list of attributes along with their types

```
a = [(f'x.{i}', type(getattr(x, i))) for i in dir(x)]
```

using defaultdict, made a dictionary, which stores attributes according to type.

```
e = defaultdict(list)
for i, j in a.items():
  e[j].append(i)
```

Comment: You should always include a description with your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Usually, the attributes you are not supposed to access start with `_` or `__`. So, `[att for att in dir(x) if not att.startswith('_')]`

If you want to exclude functions too, add `and not callable(att)` to the condition.